# How does ASIO transfer the completion handlers to one of thread of pool, by using lock or lock-free queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, boost-asio

As known, Boost.ASIO can run completion handlers in the already existed threads from thread-pool `std::vector<boost::thread>`. This allows us to remove the overhead of creating and deleting threads. But how does a Boost.ASIO transfer the next task into one of the existing thread, does it do it with a lock-based queue (std::mutex), or does it with the lock-free queue?

How optimally does he do this?

```
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  session(tcp::socket socket) : socket_(std::move(socket))
  {}

  void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            for(auto &i : data_) std::cout << i;
            do_read();
          }
        });
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};
```

---

```
int main() {

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    std::vector<boost::thread> thr_grp_executors;
    unsigned int thread_num_acceptors = 2;

    // async non-blocking executors
    for(size_t i = 0; i < thread_num_executors; ++i)
        thr_grp_executors.emplace_back( 
                boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service) );

    // sync blocking acceptor
    tcp::acceptor a(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
    for (;;)
    {
        tcp::socket sock(io_service);
        a.accept(sock);
        std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->do_read();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Will lambda-handler in the class (session) be transferd to some of thread of threads-pool by using lock-based queue, or by lock-free queue?

Comment: Are you under the impression that lock-free queues are faster than lock-based queues?

Comment: @Yakk  Yes, my interest is based on the fact that lock-free is deprived of the problem of priority inversion, and also impression is based on this benchmark: http://moodycamel.com/blog/2014/heavy32.png  more detail: http://moodycamel.com/blog/2014/a-fast-general-purpose-lock-free-queue-for-c++

Comment: So your real question is whether priority inversion is possible here?

Comment: @EJP Real question about performance.

Comment: I, too, have been wondering about this. But indeed I don't know whether it makes a difference unless you always saturate all cores, and have optimal thread affinity for tasks